When using Addressable, if a connected dependency is changed, all groups associated with the dependency must be downloaded
For example, suppose you have two prefabs preA and preB that share the material mat_new.
preA is in Group1 and preB is in Group2. All groups are set to Pack Together.
In this situation, when mat_new changes, it changes preA and preB, which were referencing it. This creates a situation where you need to download the entirety of Group1 and Group2 with the Pack Togeter setting.
To solve this, I used "https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.17/manual/DiagnosticTools.html#check-duplicate-bundle-dependencies" and "https://unity.com/blog/technology/tales-from-the-optimization-trenches-saving-memory-with-addressables" as shown in this article. I used Fixable rules in Analyze to move all the commonly referenced things to the Duplicate Asset Isolation Group.
After applying this, I noticed that when I changed the settings of Group1 and Group2, which were set to Pack Together, to Separately and then changed the mat_new that they were referencing in common, I was not downloading both Group1 and Group2, but only preA and preB, unlike my previous test.
Here are the questions I have.

how to use the Pack Together option and Fixable ruels in Analyze while avoiding situations where a change in a small piece of referenced data requires you to re-receive the entire group.
if #1 is not a workaround due to using the Pack Together option, should I change all Group settings to Separately to prevent small changes from downloading the entire group? Are there any download speed issues or memory issues to expect in this case?


Why not e.g. pack the material in a third group .. I would expect that only that third group is downloaded then when the material changes while the other two groups simply use whatever the material is now

As mentioned in your previous question the pack separately basically treats each and every root prefab/asset as an individual bundle file .. so you can react better to small grained changes but of course on the other side will have a bit more overhead regarding individual bundle downloads and loading processes and more work due to more complex dependency resolutions .. plus you increase the probability of having duplicates packed multiple times ... The better your own asset management beforehand the batter the packing .. as said shared assets should go to a third group to not be duplicated
